# How do I get the last character of a string using an Excel function?

Tags: string, excel, worksheet-function

How do I get the last character of a string using an Excel function?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No need to apologize for asking a question!  Try using the `RIGHT` function.  It returns the last *n* characters of a string.

```
=RIGHT(A1, 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
=RIGHT(A1)
```

is quite sufficient (where the string is contained in A1).

Similar in nature to LEFT, Excel's [RIGHT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/right.php) function extracts a substring from a string starting from the right-most character:

> **SYNTAX**
>
> ```
> RIGHT( text, [number_of_characters] )
> ```
>
> **Parameters or Arguments**
>
> ***text***
>
> The string that you wish to extract from.
>
> ***number_of_characters***
>
> Optional. It indicates the number of characters that you wish to extract starting from the right-most character. If this parameter is omitted, only 1 character is returned.
>
> ***Applies To***
>
> Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2011 for Mac, Excel 2010, Excel 2007, Excel 2003, Excel XP, Excel 2000

Since ***number_of_characters*** is optional and defaults to `1` it is not required in this case.

However, there have been many issues with trailing spaces and if this is a risk for the last *visible* character (in general):

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1))
```

might be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do this:

```
=MID(A1, LEN(A1), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer above was a little incomplete try the following:-

```
=RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1)))
```

Obviously, this is for cell A2...

What this does is uses a combination of Right and Len - Len is the length of a string and in this case, we want to remove all but one from that... clearly, if you wanted the last two characters you'd change the -1 to -2 etc etc etc.

After the length has been determined and the portion of that which is required - then the Right command will display the information you need.

This works well combined with an IF statement - I use this to find out if the last character of a string of text is a specific character and remove it if it is. See, the example below for stripping out commas from the end of a text string...

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,(LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1)))=",",LEFT(A2,(LEN(A2)-1)),A2)
```

Comment: `LEN(A2)-(LEN(A2)-1)` is `LEN(A2)-LEN(A2) + 1` and is `1`, right?